# getting audio file from s3 bucket to html5 audio player in flask

Tags: python, flask, amazon-s3

Using a Flask app, I am receiving a presigned url from an s3 bucket file which is .mp3 file.  I can receive the presigned url in my app.py file.  I have confirmed that the URL is valid by clicking on it and it downloads and plays the .mp3 file on my laptop.

However, when I attempt to pass the presigned url to my html template where I have an html5 audio player, the audio player doesn't register receiving the file.

I have tried:

1. Using the send_file function to an audio player that is coded this way:
2. Simply rendering the .html template and sending it the variable which is the s3 presigned URL

   return render_template('search.html', audio_url=s3_local_url)

with the html5 audio player coded this way:

```
<audio id="audio-player" controls>
       <source src="{{ audio_file }}" type="audio/mpeg">
 </audio>
```

Like I said, I know the URL is working so I only provided the return statement (which does not cause the player to receive the s3 bucket file presigned URL either)

3. Finally, I have tried wording the return this way:

   return redirect(s3_func_url)

Nothing has worked so far and I am out of ideas.  Any help getting this to work is much appreciated.

Here is the consistent Console.log error message:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
```